# How to rewrite a trigger causing an update deadlock error

Tags: sql, triggers, firebird, firebird2.5

I have the following trigger. It is executed after an update statement from a REST API request. My issue is that when it is sent two API calls concurrently, the trigger is executed twice, therefore a deadlock error comes up because the transaction is not finished. Is there any SQL trickery I can try? Can I check in table B if it already has `B_NEEDSRECALCULATION` set to `'+'` and bypass the update, or maybe create a trigger on tableb?

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER TR_TESTTRIGGER_AU FOR TABLEA
ACTIVE AFTER UPDATE POSITION 0
AS
   
begin

  if (rdb$get_context('USER_TRANSACTION', 'WISASCRIPT') = '1') then exit;
 
  if ((new.A_FiledB IS NULL) and 
      (old.A_FieldA <> new.A_FieldB) )THEN 

  begin
    UPDATE TableB        
    SET B_NEEDSRECALCULATION = '+'
    WHERE (B_TESTID = new.A_TESTIDFK);
  end

end
```

Comment: The error is probably not a real deadlock error, but likely an update conflict (which for historic reasons is grouped under deadlock error). You might be able to reduce the chance of it occurring by using a different isolation level, or by using an autonomous transaction to update tableb. However, update conflicts could still occur, so you should be prepared to retry an action. Maybe a separate table for signalling updates could help as well.

Comment: Do not update what was already updated. `UPDATE TableB SET B_NEEDSRECALCULATION = '+' WHERE ( B_NEEDSRECALCULATION IS DISTINCT FROM '+' ) AND ( .... )` and try doing it `in autonomous transaction`

Comment: Also, do you really need to track cache state as a separate column? Won't it better be to create a TABLE for it - and especially so if TableB has some tree-like or otherwise interdependent structure, when invalidating one data sell can cascade into invalidating dependent ones? - like `create table table_b_calculated(id integer primary key foreign key ....)` then your trigger would issue DELETE commands rather than update, and this would automagically account for "was already deleted" case. For compatibility sake (albeit slower) you can even recreate `B_NEEDSRECALCULATION` as `computed by` col

Comment: `from a REST API request. My issue is that when it is sent two API calls concurrently` also, if you make a 3-tier program, why would you let external requests to go right into RDBMS layer? Can you instead make such requests be first grouped in your HTTP-server application data/execution pipelines and then reach RDBMS layer de-multithreaded?

Comment: when requests are sent sequentially, right after the success callback function, then, there is no problem. I Tried B_NEEDSRECALCULATION IS DISTINCT FROM '+'  but still throwing the update conflict "-update conflicts with concurrent update   -concurrent transaction number is 21690   -At trigger TR_TESTTRIGGER_AU ..." Is there no firebird functions to LOCK a trigger transaction or something?  Coulndtr follow "first grouped in your HTTP-server application data/execution pipeline" thx man

Comment: how would i add a " iautonomous transaction" in this case?

Comment: you can `lock` a table row, but it would still make concurrent transaciton fail. https://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-notes-withlock.html
however you wrote it: "when requests are sent sequentially," there is no error. That is what your HTTP server has to do - send them sequentially. Your app-server has ot do then all the "heavy lifting" including multithreading sync, and only send streamlined sequential commands to RDBMS. Ideally, if your http clients send requests to delete rows 10, 12 and 23 - the app-server has to group them and send a single SQL command to delete all three

Comment: u also have a typo in `(old.A_FieldA <> new.A_FieldB) )THEN`  :-)

Comment: did you try turning cache markers into rows, not columns? not sure if that would work or do same update conflicts, but try. Anyway,. since your cache is a global object it perhaps has to be managed by the app-server by MREW (multi-readers exclusive writer) ways. There has to be a single thread or pipeline in your appserver that can change cache data, and all the client requests worker threads should delegate cache-related work to that single manager. That single manager would update cache in the database in sequential way. And, cache invalidation has to be recorded before data change not after

Comment: You can use autonomous transaction **in PSQL code** with [`IN AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION DO`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-inauton)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel check error propagation details though. Autonomous ones were designed for logging. If the outer, "parent transaction" failes, then the inner, "autonomous" tx changes retain committed, but only "parent" tx changes are rolled back. The TS needs **the opposite**: to ignore errors (or re-run maybe) of the inner TX, retaining the changes of outer tx. You also can not change the isolation levels, you can not create a SNAPSHOT aut-tx inside triggers called by parent rc-tx. I did not suggest error handling inside the trigger as i fear infinite loop there on non-RC txs.

Comment: one can toy, perhaps, with external transaction, re-connecting to the engine itself, but such a Rube Goldberg Machine would be too much of abuse to my tastes. Frankly, this topic is great illustration to the adage of only three things really difficult in programming :-)

Comment: One way otu would be to use ASYNC and LATE cache invalidation: to INSERT (specific case of logging) IDs to be invalidated into some log table, and then have a single-threaded worker pollinh that table and doing `B_NEEDSRECALCULATION = '+'` sequentially. This implies however there would be small time spans when data is already changed by cache was not invalidated yet. This can be okay in some workflows but not in all of those. Common sense says safe way is to invalidate cache first change data later.

Comment: Good stuff..thanks!!! will go sequentially..